# FFMPEG Streaming, using list for multiple presentations

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am currently using a third party library to transcode videos from mp4 to HLS. https://video.aminyazdanpanah.com/python/start?r=hls#hls Great documentation and works fine however I have an issue by passing a list to hls.representations() that I think is something wrong I do. Here is how I run my code.

```
presetList = []
rep_1  = Representation(Size(1920,1080), Bitrate(4096 * 1024, 320 * 1024))
                    presetList.append(rep_1)
rep_2 = Representation(Size(1440, 900), Bitrate(2048 * 1024, 320 * 1024))
                    presetList.append(rep_2)

video =  "file.mp4"
video = ffmpeg_streaming.input(video)
completed_destination = "completed.m3u8"
hls = video.hls(Formats.h264())
hls.representations(presetList)
hls.output(completed_destination)
```

When I run this I get following error, that is triggered by library meaning values in my list not passed properly?

```
  File "/var/www/transcoder/transcoder/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ffmpeg_streaming/_hls_helper.py", line 87, in stream_info
    f'BANDWIDTH={rep.bitrate.calc_overall}',
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bitrate'
```

if I instead run the same code with only change as below, works like a charm:

```
hls.representations(rep_1, rep_2)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to include *args when passing to function. As an example, instead of hls.representations(presetList) I should be doing hls.representations(*presetList)